# vue js data design strategy - Complex JSON object from API or simple JSON objects with PK/FK relationships

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, api-design

I am desiging a vue.js (vue2) app which requires a complex data set derived from 4 database tables in 3NF.  Data will be called using axios to PHP end-point(s) which will fetch data from on-prem MSSQL. Conceptually the shape of the data is as follows:

```
{
    Collection-A [
        {
          Obj1:{
            Obj1.field1,
            Obj1.field2
          },
          Obj2:{
            Obj2.field1:,
            Obj2.field2:
          },
          Collection-B:[
             {
                  CollB.field1,
                  CollB.field2,
                  CollB.Collection-C:[
                      {
                          CollC.field1:,
                          CollC.Collection-D:[0,1,2],
                          CollC.Obj3:{
                            Obj3.field1:,
                            Obj3.field2:,
                            Obj3.field3
                          },
                          CollC.Obj4:{
                            Obj4.field1:
                            Obj4.field2:
                          }
                      }...repeat Collection-C
                  ]
             }...repeat Collection-B
          ]
        }..repeat Collection-A
    ]
}
```

My question is how best to model the data for performance, understanding and reuse.

- Option 1 is to just extract the four collections into different arrays in the data() object with the fields for PK and FK then use .map and .filter to find the relevant records. This will avoid the nesting of repeated data within the object so is good for memory but will require computationally expensive lookups. It also has the benefit of keeping the APIs simple.
- Option 2 is to extract the data in it's simple form and then build the complex object for rendering. this results in double storage and I have to wait for all of the axios requests to complete: either with 4 calls or start with one call for the Collection-A data and then multiple calls for each level of data required
- Option 3 is to make a single API call and have PHP construct the data.  This will require PHP to make the four calls to the database (or iterative calls for each nested object) and will be single threaded so could be slow and I don't get any data back until the PHP object has been built.
- Option 4 is the get the database engine to build the complex object which is likely to be computationally faster as the engine is optimised.  Unfortunately my version of MSSQL only supports FOR XML and not FOR JSON so I will still need to either convert the XML to JSON in PHP (or with a js library) or build the JSON object using cursors and BCP

Options 1 or 2 feel like the cleanest solutions as the APIs are reusable and easy to test.  Unfortunately GraphQL is not an option in my current environment.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give any specific suggestion because your data model example is very simple and missing some important information such as:

1. What is the cardinality of the data? Are there only few objects in Collection-B/C used by many objects in Collection-A? (in other words how much the data bloat when de-normalized)
2. How do you use the data in your app? Just view or updates too ? Are updates to B/C collections objects needed ?
3. How big part of the whole data set does your app need at any given time ?
4. What about use cases ? How important is perceived performance for you? Is it ok to load and display just objects in collection A (in some kind of grid) and load rest of the data lazily on the background or on demand when needed ?

You need to consider all your requirements (or set some for yourself), not just technical aspects.

Anyway here are some ideas:

- Given the fact your data are already stored in normal form, Option 1 feels best. You can for example use library like [Vuex ORM](https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/guide/prologue/what-is-vuex-orm.html#issue-with-nested-relational-data) to make things easier for you (if hesitant to use "another 3rd party library", consider Vuex alone - its maintained by Vue core team).
- I strongly recommend this approach if updates to collection B/C objects are needed (as it would be hard when you need to update multiple copies of the same data)
- data representation in memory and "in transit" are different things. You can decide to keep data in normal form but load it de-normalized for performance reasons (Vuex ORM makes this [simple](https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/guide/data/inserting-and-updating.html#inserting-relationships) - can be useful for testing too)
- consider using lazy-loading if you don't need all the data at once

Comment: Thanks Michal.  Loving the standard it depends answer :) In the real data, Collection A is a list of suppliers, B is a list of products and C is the various price lists for the customer base.  The complex object is to populate a grid of data but the application will only be updating the objects in collection C, In any given data set we will probably max out at about 5000 total data points in C and the app only needs to run on desktops.  I am also leaning towards Option 1 as I think it is easier to write and unit test.